# この道をまっすぐ行ってください。 Why を and not で?

Tags: particles, particle-を

In a quiz, I got a question where one had to complete with に、を、で or が the following sentence:

> この道（？）まっすぐ行ってください。

The correct answer being:

> この道**を**まっすぐ行ってください。

It always seems more natural to me to put で here instead of を as 道 describes where the action will take place.

Could anyone please give me the reason behind this choice in Japanese?

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate):  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/78

Comment: この道で行ってください is fine though it means "please go with/via this road".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are basically four choices with motion verbs in Japanese. Each has a slightly different implication.

- に - "to" indicates the final goal of the travel. If chosen in your sentence it would be slightly nonsensical due to the この "Go directly to the street right here"
- で - "in or around" tends to indicate meandering inside of the boundaries of a location. In other words, で treats the street not as a path to travel along, but as a place to move around inside of. This might be appropriate if you were at a street-fair or similar event (although this would probably be better with a verb other than 行く). In this case, however, the まっすぐ contradicts the implication of で, so it's not appropriate here. (EDIT: As several commentators have pointed out, で is a reasonable choice if there is a discussion of which way to travel. But this requires a context in which the conversants are discussing different options: "this road", "that sidewalk", "hang-gliding")
- を - "across/along" indicates traveling the length (or a significant portion thereof) of the road/mountain/sky/(distance). More details are at [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3243)
- へ - "to" - very similar to に, and [へ can be replaced with に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2166/29) in pretty much all situations involving movement verbs. There is a slight emphasis on the "direction" with へ, such that へ is often called the "direction particle", as opposed to the "destination particle" に.

There are, of course, other possible particles for marking destinations, such as まで, までで, までに, the catch-all topic marker は, and even simple omission.

Comment: What about へ? I know it's not an answer to the question, but I think that one's worth mentioning with the other particles.

Comment: で can also mean "from", e.g. 家を出る/去る

Answer (score 8):

Building off of jkerian's answer, here are some translations which illustrate why を is the correct choice:

> この道でまっすぐ行ってください。
>
> Please go straight in this road. (nonsensical)
>
> この道をまっすぐ行ってください。
>
> Please take this road straight ahead.

Comment: If someone can provide a translation or situation where この道でまっすぐ行ってください。would make sense, please do so, as I am curious about this as well.

Comment: When there are multiple choices "で" could be used. For instance, "目的地へ行くには道路Aと道路Bがありますがどちらですか？Aで行ってください."