# Help with sentence 私が外国を歩くようになったのは・・・

Tags: translation, particles, particle-を

This clause is from a book that I'm reading called "日本人が知らない世界の歩き方". It's the first clause of the first sentence in the book and <strike>coincidentally</strike> the first one that I'm having trouble with. In particular, there are two things that I don't understand:

1. What does the を before 歩く mean? How is it possible for an intransitive verb to have an を particle? If this usage of the particle を is different than its usage as a direct object, can you please explain this alternate usage in depth?
2. What does it mean for のは to be preceded by a verb in the past tense? I understand that  when の follows a present tense verb, it forms an infinitive or gerund (i.e. 歩くの = to run or running), but I don't understand what this means when it is applied to a verb in the past tense.

*edit: I just learned from the particle-wo tag that the particle can sometimes mean the course of a motion verb. So 外国を歩く means "walk around a foreign country" or "traverse a foreign country"? What English preposition is a good approximation for this particle? And is 歩く meant to literally mean "to walk", or is it a more general type of motion like "to traverse"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Xを歩く has the meaning of walking *along* X. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6874/1628) and [this related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6869/1628).
2. のは has exactly the same meaning as when used with a present tense verb. の nominalizes whatever verb precedes it, and は makes this nominalized verb the topic of the sentence...

As it stands the sentence is incomplete, so the only way is to translate it freely. I would say something like

> (About) How I started to walk on foreign territories...

but it really depends on the text. A freer translation might fit even better.

Comment: I still don't understand what it means to nominalize a verb in the past tense.

Comment: @phoenixheart6 Nominalizing a verb allows you to use the verb as the subject/topic of a sentence. E.g. "I like drinking beer" ビールを飲むのが好きです. Or, in the past tense, バイトをして自身を持てるようになったのは、仕事で頑張れるのにとても大事なことでした "The fact that I had gained self-confidence during my part-time job was really important for my motivation at work". (Actually, the nominalizer の appears twice here.)

Comment: Ok, so when used in the past tense it's "the fact that"? I think I understand then. I was confused because I normally think of nominalizing as turning it into an infinitive or a gerund. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @phoenixheart6 Yeah, I do, too. There is no past tense gerund, though. Sometimes the perfect tense fits well, and then you can use the gerund for the auxiliary. If there were a past tense gerund, it would be the way of translating it. The concept in Japanese is really the same.