# Particle for "in the water"

Tags: grammar, particles, song-lyrics

In Miyuki Nakajima's song "ファイト！" there is this line:

冷たい水の中をふるえながらのぼってゆけ

I don't understand the use of the particle を in this context.
Shouldn't it be に or even で?

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/%e3%81%93%e3%81%ae%e9%81%93%e3%82%92%e3%81%be%e3%81%a3%e3%81%99%e3%81%90%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84%e3%80%82why-%e3%82%92-and-not-%e3%81%a7

Comment: I don't understand the closevote. I also don't understand @dainichi's link. It's obvious what 道を行く is meant to mean, but it's not at all obvious to me what 水の中を上って行け is meant to mean. I think this is a good question.

Comment: However, to be useful to DaleyPaley: I'm sure what dainichi was hinting at was that this particle is a particle demanded by 行く, rather than a particle that means "in the water". Actually, my best attempt at a translation (bearing in mind that I might have misunderstood this) would be "rise through the water", not "in". If anything means "in" at all, it is probably 中.

Comment: @Billy, the question isn't asking about the meaning, it's asking why it's を and not に or で. The accepted answer of the question I linked to answers exactly that.

Comment: Yes, I am perfectly happy with the close vote, I got my answer from the link. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Billy:  Actually the `を` is required by `のぼる` in this case, not the `ゆく（ゆけ）`.