# Multiple "wo"s in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntax, particle-を

I had always been told this never happened. I was a little skeptical, but since I never saw a sentence with two of the particle, I gradually came to accept that it was probably true.

Well ironically, in the DoBJG, where I'm pretty sure I've also read the above factoid, I've encountered this sentence:

この道を靴を履かずに歩けますか。

So I'm wondering if this is a mistake, or a weird exception, or if this "rule" I've heard is simply misleading or outright fallacious, and if so, when is it okay to use multiple wo particles in a sentence.

Cheers.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16289/

Comment: It is SO common that I wonder why anyone would teach you otherwise.

Comment: DoBJG actually says more than once in a *clause*.  (p.348)  There are very few exceptions, though Martin discusses some examples on pages 255-256 of his 1975 *Reference Grammar of Japanese*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple case of subclauses - you've still got one を per clause:

[この道を[靴を履かずに]歩けますか。]

靴 is the object of 履かず, 道 is the object* of 歩けます.

*Depending on your interpretation of を with what you would think are intransitive verbs. You can read more about these sorts of cases here: [It seems that 渡る is categorized as 自動詞 (intransitive verb), yet it is frequently used with を. Why?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12734/3639)

Comment: But I thought that subclauses don't change this. Or is that only nominalised sentences that don't change it?

Comment: You mean, you understand the rule to be one を per sentence, regardless of subclauses? That's definitely not the case. It's kind of the case with は - you're not suppose to have any in subclauses, though you're allowed multiple は's as long as they're in the main clause.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood it. So wait, does that mean you can have an wo in a nominalised sentence, or is that still off limits for some reason?

Comment: Nope, that's fine - 映画を見るのが好き is perfectly valid. You can't use it with just a straight 連用形 (eg 走り, 見), but those are much closer to derived nouns than nominalised verbs anyway.

Comment: (If it helps, 映画を見るのを待ってる is also totally valid.)

Comment: I see. Of course, I've seen that kind of nominalised sentence before, but for whatever reason it didn't register. I think I must have misread/misunderstod some finer point being made at some point. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! ^_^

Comment: Contrastive は is possible in subordinate clauses.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason here is that those two を apply to two different verbs.

この道**を**[靴を履かずに]**歩けます**か。