# Questions about causative constructions

Tags: grammar, causation

If I wanted to say "The teacher who made the kids write a letter to their friend in the hospital", how should I write it?

Are 2 にs ok in the same sentence?
Would 病院にいる友達に子供に手紙を書かせた先生。be acceptable?

If there are no particles, how should I interpret a causative like 書かせた人

Would it be

1. The person who made someone else write
2. The person who was made to write by someone

Comment: 病院にいる友達への手紙を子供に書かせた先生。

Comment: 「子供に、入院してる友達**宛てに**手紙を書かせた…」でもいいかと。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence would be at least understandable if you change the word order and write like this:

> 子供に病院にいる友達に手紙を書かせた先生

It's because this sentence will be parsed like this (with "nesting"):

> [子供に[病院にいる友達に手紙を書か]せた]先生

The "病院にいる友達に手紙を書く" part should be written as one verbal phrase because that's the action the child has to take.

This question is more or less similar: [Multiple "wo"s in a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23261/5010)

---

That said, it would be much better if you can avoid multiple に's like this. Multiple に both marking a person is hard for even native speakers to understand. The simplest way to fix this is using へ instead.

> - 子供に病院にいる友達**へ**手紙を書かせた先生
> - 子供に病院にいる友達**への**手紙を書かせた先生
> - 病院にいる友達**への**手紙を子供に書かせた先生
>     <sub>(This is okay, as @優しいエイリアン suggested, because への modifies 手紙, and 病院にいる友達への手紙 is one noun phrase)</sub>
> - [*] 病院にいる友達へ手紙を子供に書かせた先生 (**wrong**)
>     <sub>(Can you see why this is wrong? へ modifies the verb 書く. The "nest" structure will be broken if you write like this)</sub>

---

And I see nothing wrong with sentences like this:

> - 子供に夜にお菓子を食べさせるのは良くない。
> - 夜に子供にお菓子を食べさせるのは良くない。
> - 夜にお菓子を子供に食べさせるのは良くない。
>     <sub>(uncommon word order, but perfectly makes sense)</sub>

Comment: I see, sometimes though I find some sentences where the particle does not refer to the first verb after it.  "病院にいる友達へ手紙を子供に書かせた先生 " I found a sentence similar to this once, that is why I used it an example.  Thanks.  Anyway for the second part of the question could you help me out?

Comment: If there are no particles how should i interpret a causative like this
書かせた人
The person who made someone else write
The person who was made to write by somoene"

Comment: 書かせた人 always means "person who made (someone) write", and 書かされた人 is "person who was made to write".

Comment: 僕が書かせた人 means:"The man who I forced to write something" ?

Comment: Yes..................................

Comment: @Splikie: And 僕に書かせられた人 is the man who was forced by me to write .