# Use of 'wo' in "umi no naka wo oyogu yo"

Tags: particle-を, verbs-of-motion

> 海の中を泳ぐよ
>   *umi no naka wo oyogu yo*

"wo" is the direct object particle, so does this mean "swim the in the sea?" But that doesn't make much sense.

This was from a children's colouring sheet showing a character swimming through the sea. Nothing else was written.

Comment: Can you clarify: which part of sentence you translated as `the`? In my opinion "the" is quite unique in English and has not a direct analogue in Japanese (as in my mother tongue - Russian too)

Comment: I first interpreted the Japanese sentence as "swim the sea," similar to "eat the apple." That is why I wrote "swim the in the sea" as my first translation.

Answer (score 2):

It actually means "swim through the sea!"(Exclamation added because the sentence ends with yo.)

Some motion verbs use "wo" instead of "ni" despite being intransitive.
See: [Direct objects of motion verbs and help with the difference between を and に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61071/direct-objects-of-motion-verbs-and-help-with-the-difference-between-%E3%82%92-and-%E3%81%AB)

Answer (score 1):

With verbs of motion,

- に and へ indicate destination
- を means 'along (road, river)' or 'across' (going from A to B)
- で is where you do something (not going anywhere).

The latter case has no real change of location, like swimming in a pool. To me this is simply the で for verbs of action (swimming in a pool is an action but does not go anywhere, so in this context it is not a verb of motion).

を is foremost the particle for direct objects, but that does not mean that it always is. Likewise, に is the particle for indirect objects, but one does not generally consider that '[place]に' is an indirect object.