Usage of を in 雨の中を走る
I just came across this phrase when reading 人間失格: 雨の中を走る. I can not get my head around the usage of を here.

Maybe some of the links in Naruto's answer to this earlier question would answer your question as well? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61071/direct-objects-of-motion-verbs-and-help-with-the-difference-between-を-and-に


He runs through the rain.

For intransitive verbs of motion, を can be used to express an idea similar to through.

道を歩いた。
She walked down the street


川を泳いだ。
They swam across the river.

