# Meaning of を in「 未来を少しでも君といたい」

Tags: grammar, particle-を, song-lyrics

In the song [アスノヨゾラ[哨戒班]{しょうかいはん}](https://utaten.com/lyric/sa16041508/) there is this lyric:

> [未来]{みらい}**を**[少]{すこ}しでも[君]{きみ}といたいから[叫]{さけ}ぼう
>
> 〝[今日]{きょう}の[日]{ひ}をいつか[思]{おも}い[出]{だ}せ[未来]{みらい}の[僕]{ぼく}ら！〟

What role is **を** playing in the first line? There are no transitive verbs, so it doesn't look like it's marking [未来]{みらい} as the direct object of a verb, unlike in the second line where を clearly marks [今日]{きょう}の[日]{ひ} as the direct object of [思]{おも}い[出]{だ}す.

I'm aware that を has [some other uses](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%92) but I'm not familiar enough with them to see which one applies here.

Comment: Definition 3 in Jisho. I believe this を belongs to the verb いたい. It is similar to the one used in 公園を歩く.

Comment: @JimmyYang might have the right of it.  This still strikes me as weird usage -- for _"an area [or time] traversed"_, I'd expect a different verb that includes some such sense of "traversing" or "spending time", such as 過【す】ごす or 暮【く】らす. Googling just now, 「未来をいて」 [generates only three hits](https://www.google.com/search?q="未来をいて"), of which [only one](https://www.reservestock.jp/events/651274) actually uses this phrase.

Comment: I didn't realize 形容詞 could be transitive? o_O

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, if you mean the 形容詞 that is いたい (i.e. 居たい), this construction appears to be relatively recent from other discussions I've had (arising in just the last century or so?). The basic parsing seems to have shifted, so that the ～たい ending, rather than creating an adjective from the verb so that the adjective now requires が, is instead applied to the fuller verbal phrase. So things like 鶏肉を食べたい become grammatically possible, where the ～たい is viewed as （鶏肉を食べる）＋たい. Sounds like it changes the nuance when using を vs. が, emphasis on the overall action with を, vs. on the noun with が.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This を is probably a location marker which is roughly the same as English *across* or *through* (or sometimes *along*).

- [Making sense of transitive usage of 行く and 来る - 「を行く」 and 「を来る」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/5010)
- [Why does 出る accept を although it is an intransitive verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21313/5010)
- [この道をまっすぐ行ってください。 Why を and not で?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6869/5010)
- [It seems that 渡る is categorized as 自動詞 (intransitive verb), yet it is frequently used with を. Why?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12734/5010)

It's basically used with **intransitive verbs of motion** such as 行く, 進む, 飛ぶ, 出る and 渡る. いる is not a verb which is typically used with を in ordinary sentences, but it's understandable at least in lyrics. You may think this いる has temporarily gained a connotation of "to go on" or "to proceed".

- Perfectly natural: 未来を君と歩みたい, 未来を君と進みたい
- Also natural: 未来を君と生きたい, 未来を君と過ごしたい
- Understandable in lyrics as an extension of above: 未来を君といたい