# "In my dream, I ran through a meadow full of flowers" -> 夢の中で、花がいっぱい草地で走っていた

Tags: grammar, translation

So, I'm trying to build "In my dream, I ran through a meadow full of flowers" in Japanese, but I'm having some problems...

1. Is 夢の中で a valid way of saying "In the dream"?
2. Should that comma be there?
3. The 花がいっぱい草地で　to say "In a field/meadow full of flowers" part is correct?

Comment: See [この道をまっすぐ行ってください。 Why を and not で?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6869/78).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [この道をまっすぐ行ってください。 Why を and not で?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/%e3%81%93%e3%81%ae%e9%81%93%e3%82%92%e3%81%be%e3%81%a3%e3%81%99%e3%81%90%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84-why-%e3%82%92-and-not-%e3%81%a7)

Comment: @A.Ellett  That only answers part 3 of the questions, but not parts 1 and 2.

Comment: @ajsmart Very true.  I had a brain fart maybe?  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is 夢の中で a valid way of saying "In the dream"?

Yes.

> 2. Should that comma be there?

It doesn't matter.

> 3. The 花がいっぱい草地で　to say "In a field/meadow full of flowers" part is correct?

No. Your sentence is perfectly grammatical but 花がいっぱい走っていた means "[flowers were running in flocks](https://stock.adobe.com/images/spring-background-with-running-flowers-the-idea-for-kids-or-cards-vector-illustration/102686678)". You have to say 花がいっぱい**の**草地**を**走っていた. いっぱい without の is an adverb that modifies the next verb (走る). With this の, 花がいっぱい is parsed as a relative clause that modifies 草地:

- 草地は花がいっぱいだ。
  The field is full of flowers.
- 花がいっぱいの草地
  the field which is full of flowers

And to say "through/across", you need to use を before 走る. See: [この道をまっすぐ行ってください。 Why を and not で?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6869/5010)

Comment: thanks a lot! This is a very well explained answer. <3