# Do particles like を、で、に、and へ、form noun-phrases?

Tags: grammar, nuances, particles, nouns

Can particles like を、で、に、and へ be used like nouns?

Can you do something like:

> [ 学校 + に ] + の + 学生 + です。= 学校にの学生です。
> [ School + at ] + *'s + student + is. = To-be at-school's student.

Is this kind of structure allowed? Even if my example doesn't make sense, can you do things like this? And if so, can you give me some examples of it being used properly?

Comment: What is 学校にの学生 supposed to mean?

Comment: What I'm asking is whether or not "学校に" can be used like a NP, allowing for particles like の like it does は.

Comment: @naruto If it were good grammar I'd interpret 学校にの学生 to be 学校にいる学生. I know you can write things like 田中さんへの手紙. So 田中さんへ , as a whole, kind of acts like a noun. So, insights into when/why you can do this would interest me. Of course, if this isn't what he meant then please just ignore my ramblings.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2167/1478

Comment: @user3856370 We should first learn that に is not "in" unless it's combined with specific verbs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you cannot treat 学校で like a noun. It's an *adverbial modifier*. But you can turn them into adjective-like phrases by saying [での, への, との, からの, までの, and so on](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/5010). をの does not exist. にの is very rare and you should use への instead.

BTW, 学校にの学生です makes no sense to me.

Comment: I can't believe that にの is very rare instead of being impossible.